# How to import config vars from window in Enzyme/Sinon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, sinon

I have a react application that went from storing config vars (urls, mostly) in config files to storing those same variables in `window.envs`, for reasons that are out of scope for this question.

Header contains a simple script tag:

```
<script src="env-vars.js"></script>
```

Variables are laded into `window`

```
// env-vars.js
window.envs = {
  QA_URL: 'qa.catdog.com'
  ...
}
```

Variables are made available to the app:

```
// envs.js
export default window.envs;
```

Then `envs.js` is imported into whatever component needs them.

```
import envs from 'config/envs';
```

This solution works for the app itself. Unfortunately, the change broke a lot of unit tests.

Given that the the `env` vars have to live in `window` and cannot be imported directly (at least no by the app, the unit tests can do what they want), how can I go about making `window` variables available to unit tests?

EDIT: the unit test stack is Enzyme/Mocha/Chai. Sinon too.

Comment: you can try `global.window = { envs: QA_URL: 'qa.catdog.com' }`

Comment: What are you using as a test runner? Jest?